# Intel NUC can't see USB HID hub on Mint Linux

Tags: usb, linux-mint, kvm-switch, hid

I have an Intel NUC5i3RYH (i3, 1TB hard drive, 4GB memory) on which I have installed Linux Mint 20.2 Uma 64-bit. This is attached to a KVM which provides a single USB connector for keyboard and mouse. Although the keyboard and mouse work fine with every other computer attached to it, the NUC stubbornly refuses to accept keyboard or mouse input from the KVM. As a test, I connected the KVM's PS/2 ports to a dollar-store adapter, and it still doesn't see the KVM's keyboard and mouse; system info does, however, show that one USB port is connected to a "PCPlay Keyboard+Mouse Adapter" with driver hid-generic, usb-hid 1.1. Clearly I'm missing something, but what?

Answer (score 0):

Forgot the basic rule - look for common factors. Either the KVM port or the KVM cable was bad. Changed port and cable and now it works... clue was that when I looked at system information when the KVM's USB cable was plugged in, there was no entry for a USB HID device.